# AngularJS ngOptions expression for object data source - is it possible to store the property key somewhere?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For an object which looks like this:

```
{
"2014":[1,2,7,8,11],
"2013":[6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
"2012":[1,2,4,7,8,12],
};
```

(For reference keys are years, values are arrays of months when some event occurs.)

Using `ng-options="year for (year, months) in yearMonths"` expression I get keys(years) displayed in the dropdown list, and selecting one fills the model with the value(months) array. That's what I want and I've got no problems with that, however I'd also like to store the selected key(year) somewhere since I need to pass it along to another method.

Is it possible to pull this off or have I went with a wrong approach?

So far I've tried changing the expression in hopes of binding both the key and the value to the model. I've tried creating expressions:

`select (year, months) as year for (year,months) in yearMonths` - shows nothing 
`year for (year, (year, months)) in yearMonths` - malformed expression exception

but to be frank I don't quite understand the expressions for ngOptions and ngRepeat for that matter ( what does select actually do and how is it used, I haven't seen any examples of it yet)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You could try a different approach and format your data differently to avoid that issue?

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas I can't format the data differently because I recieve the data from a web service. Which part of my question isn't clear? What I want is to store both the key and the value into the bound model of ngSelect instead of just the value.

Comment: Yes you can! You receive the data from the web service in the controller (or the model). There you can apply whatever logic you want to make easier for you to use.
It's better to put as few logic as possible in the view.

Comment: I could probably try to parse that relatively large object and create an array of smaller objects but I believe that that would negatively affect the performance of the application, wherein fetching the required values or changing the expression like in the answer would probably work faster (I always assume that large, famous libraries are optimized to work faster than what I could hack up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this notation specified in the `ng-options` **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)**:

`select as label for (key , value) in object`

> select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of
>   the parent  element

This means that whatever format you decide(variable or object) in the `select` expression then it will be bound to the model itself.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/or5abb8x/)**

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="{year: year, months: months} as year for (year, months) in years" ng-model="currentYear"></select>
```

The `ng-options` above suggests that when you choose a year, the model will be bound to the a JSON object with a `year` and `months` key-value.

**UPDATE:**

Using an object as the `select` expression does not tie the `ngModel`'s `$viewValue` with the current selected value. I have investigated it further and it seems this is how `ng-options` really works, it parses the `select` expression(it requires a string expression after all, reference line [404 - 406](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js#L404)). Since it locates its `viewValue` by the `valueFn` which matches the `select` expression in line **[331](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js#L331)** of their github repository, then mapping the original source value of the currently selected option value is not possible if it is in object notation.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/or5abb8x/1/)**

Alternatively you can do this:

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="year as year for (year, months) in years" ng-model="currentYear"></select><br /><br />
Current Year: {{currentYear}}<br />
Months: {{years[currentYear]}}
```

Comment: And that's exactly what I wanted. That 'select' explanation in docs is a bit lacking in my opinion, and I didn't find any examples so I was, figuratively speaking, punching shadows. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Although I seem to have noticed an issue. Not sure if it's tied to a browser (I'm using Firefox 31.0) but the selected value is not displayed in the dropdown menu (eg. in your fiddle selecting "2014" does correctly bind the values to the model but the dropdown menu remains blank instead of showing the currently selected year "2014")

Comment: That works. I've forgotten that JS objects can be used like a dictionary with C++ style notation. Thanks for your help.